# How do you check the status of your database backup (in pgadmin 4)?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I started the backup with pgadmin 4. I unfortunately exited out of the process watcher box thingy. Now I'm not sure how to tell if the backup process is complete or still in progress.

Comment: for now im just gonna periodically check the file it's writing to for date modified and file size

Answer (score 1):

If you started backup in plain mode you can check the tail of the file for:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Otherwise the simples way is checking the server `pg_stat_activity` for running backup session, as it should disconnect cluster on complete